# question about brownian motion and integration

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

If $X(t)$ is the standard Brownian motion, $0<\alpha<\beta$, and $T$ is the first exit time of $X(t)$ from $[-\beta,\beta]$, then how can I find $E(\int_0^T \mathbb{I}_{(-\alpha,\alpha)} X(t) dt)$

Comment: It seems like this should satisfy some sort of Kolmogorov equation. Yet it also seems somewhat complicated, because the process goes in and out of $(-\alpha,\alpha)$ uncountably many times. Here's one idea: if you knew $T=t_0$, could you solve the problem? From there you could integrate against $P[T=t_0]$ (which, as I recall, can be calculated explicitly) to finish.

Comment: Do you know Tanaka's formula/local times?

Comment: @saz No I don't can you give me some more detail?